# Can i change the button's content in MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: iphone

I want to use `MFMessageComposeViewController` to send a message. Can I change the button's content? For example, from "Send" to "OK"?

Comment: no there is no such option available.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to customize the `MFMessageComposeViewController` by apple.  
Check in the Apple Documentation for [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

NO,You can't  change the content of send button in `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Check in the Apple Documentation for [MFMessageComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)  there is no such option available

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, you can add this:

```
messageCtroller.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem.title = @"fire";
//original is "**cancel**";
messageCtroller.viewControllers.lastObject navigationItem].title = @"something";
//original is  "**New Message**".
```